# How do the inner workings of the Rust link attribute compare to linking in C?

Tags: c, linker, rust, dynamic-linking

I am seriously impressed with how easy the `link` attribute makes linking to shared libraries. However, I am curious about the the details of the attribute and how it compares to linking in C. For instance, given the following Rust code

```
#[allow(bad_style)]

struct wl_display;

fn main() {
    #[link(name="wayland-client", kind="dylib")]
    extern {
        fn wl_display_connect(name: *const u8) -> *mut wl_display;
    }

    // do work
}
```

Would it translate closer to something like the following C code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

struct wl_display;

int main() {
    struct wl_display* (*pwl_display_connect)(const char *name);
    char* error;

    void* handle = dlopen("/usr/lib/libwayland-client.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if(!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening lib: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    pwl_display_connect = dlsym(handle, "wl_display_connect");

    // do work

    if(!pwl_display_connect) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading function: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    if(dlclose(handle) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing lib: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with with

```
clang -o test test.c -ldl # or your cc of choice
```

Or would it translate to something like using `clang <other stuff> -lwayland-core`? Or am I entirely wrong and headed in the wrong direction?

The following is the only documentation I found from reading through the [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html)

> `link` - indicate that a native library should be linked to for the
>   declarations in this block to be linked correctly. `link` supports an
>   optional `kind` key with three possible values: `dylib`, `static`, and
>   `framework.`

#### Edit:

[The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/README.html) has some more information under [Advanced Linking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/advanced-linking.html)

Comment: If you're on a *nix-like system, try running `ldd your-exe` on both versions and compare.  The C version will definitely not report a dependency on `libwayland-client` - what about the Rust version?

Comment: Good comment! I used `RTLD_LAZY` which means "resolve undefined symbols as code from the dynamic library is executed" taken from the following documentation [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html). I didn't use `pwl_display_connect`, as this is an example, so I suspect if you were to use `RTLD_NOW` it would report a dependency, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You're wrong, the C program would not statically depend on `libwayland-client` even if you did use `RTLD_NOW`.

Comment: @Shepmaster is correct when it fails it shows the command used with the output `-l<name>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't **know** this to be true, I'm simply basing this answer based on the compiler's output.

I am on OS X and do not have anything Wayland-related installed. If I take your code and compile it with `cargo build --verbose`, I get this output (cleaned up a bit):

```
   Compiling wat v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/wat)
     Running `rustc src/main.rs --crate-name wat --crate-type bin -g --out-dir /private/tmp/wat/target/debug --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/private/tmp/wat/target/debug -L dependency=/private/tmp/wat/target/debug/deps`
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
note: "cc" "-m64" "-L" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "/private/tmp/wat/target/debug/wat.0.o" "-o" "/private/tmp/wat/target/debug/wat" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/private/tmp/wat/target/debug" "-L" "/private/tmp/wat/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "-l" "wayland-client" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-ca1c970e.rlib" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcollections-ca1c970e.rlib" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_unicode-ca1c970e.rlib" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librand-ca1c970e.rlib" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-ca1c970e.rlib" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-ca1c970e.rlib" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-ca1c970e.rlib" "/Users/shep/Projects/rust/x86_64-apple-darwin/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-ca1c970e.rlib" "-l" "System" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "c" "-l" "m" "-l" "compiler-rt"
note: ld: library not found for -lwayland-client
```

A few highlights from that:

> `"cc" [...] "-l" "wayland-client"`
>
> `ld: library not found for -lwayland-client`

From that output, I believe that this is doing normal compile-time linking to a dynamic library, not run-time loading of a dynamic library.

---

Run-time loading of a dynamic library used to be handled by [`std::dynamic_lib`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/dynamic_lib/index.html), but one should now use a crate. I'm not sure what crate is best, but I did find [libloading](https://github.com/nagisa/rust_libloading/).

---

As some editorial, I would suggest creating [a `mylibrary-sys` crate](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages) that simply exposes the direct FFI bindings. In that crate, use [the `links` key](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#the-links-manifest-key) to specify that you are linking to a native library. This allows Cargo to ensure that the native library is only linked to once. Then you don't need any attributes.